# How to use functions/variables in DBLinq.MySQL

Tags: mysql, dblinq

This is my query:

```
SELECT IF(@@old_passwords, Old_Password(?), Password(?))=`password` AS pass
FROM mysql.user WHERE User=?
```

Can I translate this to Linq, or do I have to just extract the connection from the data context and do it the old way? All the documentation I can find is about simple queries: selects; joins; aggregates.